# Localizing both Routes and URL paths in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a multilingual site in both english and spanish. I've also used the 'route_translator' gem to have the routes translated. I've created a button at the top menu to change the language and it works fine.

The problems comes when I need also to change the url itself. 
If I have URLs like this works fine:

```
/news (english)
/es/noticias (spanish)
```

But if I have something like:

```
/news/{news_id}/{news_title}

/news/15248/the-best-concert-in-the-world
/es/noticias/15248/mejor-concierto-del-mundo
```

And I try to change the language I get an url like this:

```
/es/noticias/15248/the-best-concert-in-the-world
```

The route has been translated but the 'news_title' remains (obviously) in english.

I don't know how to fix this, any ideas?

P.S.: Some code (Still not newbie in Ruby :))

I use this gem (https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator) to get the routes localized:

```
localized do
    get '/news/:reference/:slug', to:'news#show_by_url', as: :news
end
```

And

```
def show_by_url
    news_ref = params[:reference]
    slug = params[:slug]

    @news = News.with_translations(I18n.locale).find_by_reference(news_ref)
    if not slug.eql? @news.slug
        @news = nil # I know this is crap
    end 
    render 'show_by_url'
end
```

Comment: Can you show the code how it gets changed? Routes. Controllers

Comment: Done. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you following this? https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator/wiki/Generating-translated-URLs

Comment: `slug` in the url must be coming from your database. Do you store different values of slug for different locales?